# Python While Loop program CSE

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration

I have a program that I need to complete but I'm not sure how to. I need to have it use a while loop and ask if they would like to order, and once they are done if they would like to order again, and return back to the main block of code. I am not good at this at all. Here is what I have right now: (edit: sorry about the screenshot)

```
order= input('Hi, would you like to order anything? Yes (y), No (n)')
if order == "n":
    print("Ok have a nice day")
elif order == "y":
    ordering_y = type_of_sandwich = input('What kind of sandwich would you like? Chicken for $5.25 (c), Tofu for $5.75 (t), Beef for $6.25(b)?')
if type_of_sandwich == "c":
  print('You chose the chicken sandwich for $5.25')
elif type_of_sandwich == "t":
  print ('You chose a tofu for $5.75 sandwich')
elif type_of_sandwich == "b":
  print('You chose a beef sandwich for $6.25')
bev = input("Would you like a beverage? Yes (y), No (n)?")
if bev == "n":
    print("Ok, thanks for your business, would you like to order again?")
elif bev == "y":
  size= input('Small for $1.00 (s), Medium for $1.75 (m), Large for $2.25 (l)?')
if size == "s":
        print("You ordered a small beverage for $1.00, would you like to order again?")
elif size == "m":
        print("You ordered a Medium beverage for $1.75, would you like to order again?")
elif size == "l":
        print("You ordered a large beverage for $2.25, would you like to order again?")

order_again= input('Would you like to order again? Yes (y), No (n)')
while true:
    if order_again == "n":
        print("Ok, thanks for your business.")
        break
    elif order_again =="y":
        repeat order
```

Comment: Please paste your code here as a text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you further, we need more details. Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve] for tips on how to improve your question so we can provide the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `while True: runCode() ... done = input('Are you finished?') ... if done = 'Yes': break.... else: continue` ... So by the looks of your code, you'll just need another `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
def order_sandwich(key=None):
    if not key:
        type = input(
            "What Kind of Sandwich Would you like? \n (c) Chiken for $5.25 \n (t) Tofu for $5.75 \n (b) Beef for $6.25 \n (e) No Thanks \n\n Option: "
        )
        menu_sandwich(type)
    elif key == "e":
        print("Thank you")
    else:
        type = input("Please use specifed option [c, t, b]: ")
        menu_sandwich(type)

def order_beverage(key=None):
    order_drink = input(
        "Would you like a beverage? \n (y) Yes \n (n) No \n\n Option: ")
    if order_drink == "y":
        menu_beverage()
    else:
        order_again = input(
            "Ok Thanks, would you like to order again?\n (y) Yes \n (n) No\n\n Option: "
        )
        if order_again == "y":
            order_sandwich()
        else:
            print("ok have a nice day!")

def menu_sandwich(type=None):
    if type == "c":
        print("Chiken\n")
        order_beverage()
    elif type == "t":
        print("Tofu\n")
        order_beverage()
    elif type == "b":
        print("Beef\n")
        order_beverage()
    else:
        order_sandwich(type)


def menu_beverage(type=None):
    if type == "s":
        print("Small\n")
        main_order()
    elif type == "m":
        print("Medium\n")
        main_order()
    elif type == "l":
        print("Large\n")
        main_order()
    elif type == "e":
        print("ok have a nice day!")
    else:
        type = input(
            " (s) small for $1.00 \n (m) medium for $1.75 \n (l) large for $2.25 \n (e) No Thanks \n\n Option: "
        )
        menu_beverage(type)


def main_order():
  order = input("Hi, would you like to order anything? \n (y) Yes \n (n) No \n\n Options: ")
  if order == "y":
    order_sandwich()
  else:
    print("ok have a nice day!")


main_order()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `break` after user inputs 'n'. It breaks the loop and comes out of while.

Answer (score 0):

here is your code check it:

```
def order():
    order= input('Hi, would you like to order anything? Yes (y), No (n)')

    if order == "n":
        print("Ok have a nice day")
        return False
    elif order == "y":
        ordering_y = type_of_sandwich = input('What kind of sandwich would you like? Chicken for $5.25 (c), Tofu for $5.75 (t), Beef for $6.25(b)?')
    if type_of_sandwich == "c":
      print('You chose the chicken sandwich for $5.25')
    elif type_of_sandwich == "t":
      print ('You chose a tofu for $5.75 sandwich')
    elif type_of_sandwich == "b":
      print('You chose a beef sandwich for $6.25')
    bev = input("Would you like a beverage? Yes (y), No (n)?")
    if bev == "n":
        print("Ok, thanks for your business, would you like to order again?")
    elif bev == "y":
      size= input('Small for $1.00 (s), Medium for $1.75 (m), Large for $2.25 (l)?')
    if size == "s":
            print("You ordered a small beverage for $1.00, would you like to order again?")
    elif size == "m":
            print("You ordered a Medium beverage for $1.75, would you like to order again?")
    elif size == "l":
            print("You ordered a large beverage for $2.25, would you like to order again?")
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if order():
        order_again = input('Would you like to order again? Yes (y), No (n)')
        if order_again == "n":
            print("Ok, thanks for your business.")
        elif order_again =="y":
           order()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for.     :)

Comment: make answer button green

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I'm not sure if I did this right, but now it is giving me a syntax error on line 7.

```
while True:
    order= input('Hi, Would you like to order anything? Yes (y), No (n)')
    if order=="n":
        print("ok have a nice day")
        break
    elif order=="y":
 ordering = type_of_sandwich = input('What kind of sandwich would you like? Chicken for $5.25 (c), Tofu for $5.75 (t), Beef for $6.25(b)?')
if type_of_sandwich == "c":
  print('You chose the chicken sandwich for $5.25')
elif type_of_sandwich == "t":
  print ('You chose a tofu for $5.75 sandwich')
elif type_of_sandwich == "b":
  print('You chose a beef sandwich for $6.25')
bev = input("Would you like a beverage? Yes (y), No (n)?")
if bev == "n":
    print("Ok, thanks for your business.")
elif bev == "y":
  size= input('Small for $1.00 (s), Medium for $1.75 (m), Large for $2.25 (l)?')
if size == "s":
        print("You ordered a small beverage for $1.00.")
elif size == "m":
        print("You ordered a Medium beverage for $1.75.")
elif size == "l":
        print("You ordered a large beverage for $2.25.")
```

Comment: You got some really funky indention in your code. Also, this is the answers section and you filled out an answer. You are able to comment on someone's answer. This website isn't formatted to be like a blog.

Comment: Sorry, I just made my account. I was having a lot of trouble with this (it's a school assignment). I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_order():
    ordering_y = type_of_sandwich = input('What kind of sandwich would you like? Chicken for $5.25 (c), Tofu for $5.75 (t), Beef for $6.25(b)?')
    if type_of_sandwich == "c":
            print('You chose the chicken sandwich for $5.25')
    elif type_of_sandwich == "t":
            print ('You chose a tofu for $5.75 sandwich')
    elif type_of_sandwich == "b":
            print('You chose a beef sandwich for $6.25')
    bev = input("Would you like a beverage? Yes (y), No (n)?")
    if bev == "n":
        print("Ok, thanks for your business, would you like to order again?")
    elif bev == "y":
        size= input('Small for $1.00 (s), Medium for $1.75 (m), Large for $2.25 (l)?')
        if size == "s":
            print("You ordered a small beverage for $1.00, would you like to order again?")
        elif size == "m":
            print("You ordered a Medium beverage for $1.75, would you like to order again?")
        elif size == "l":
            print("You ordered a large beverage for $2.25, would you like to order again?")

while True:
    order= input('Hi, would you like to order anything? Yes (y), No (n)')
    if order == "n":
        print("Ok have a nice day")
        break
    elif order == "y":
        get_order()
    order_again= input('Would you like to order again? Yes (y), No (n)')
    if order_again == "n":
        print("Ok, thanks for your business.")
        break
    elif order_again == "y":
        get_order()
```